# Typescript Promises: How to use certain data within the promise

Tags: typescript, promise

The desired data I want to use from my component is

```
  .subscribe(setting => {
        this.retrievedSettings = setting;
        return this.retrievedSettings;
      });
```

However, the data being return is an Observable which I can't (or don't know how to) get the object data that I want.

I've tried saving

```
this.retrievedSettings = setting;
```

to another observable but it didn't work;

Service

```
retrievedSettings : SettingsModel;

async getUserSettings(userID : string) {
 const firebaseToken = await 
 this.angularFireAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true);
let searchParams = new HttpParams();
 searchParams = searchParams.set('auth', firebaseToken);
 searchParams = searchParams.append('id', userID);

 return this.http.get<{ [userID: string]: SettingsModel }>(API.DB_URL + API.userSettings,
  {
    params: searchParams
  })
  .pipe(
    map(responseData => {
      let settings : SettingsModel;
      for (const key in responseData) {
        if (responseData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          if(responseData[key].id === userID) {
            settings = responseData[key];
          }
        }
      }
    return settings;
    }),

    catchError(errorResponse => {
    return throwError(errorResponse);
    })
    )
      .subscribe(setting => {
        this.retrievedSettings = setting;
        return this.retrievedSettings;
      });
```

}

Component calling the method

```
  getUserSettings() {  
   const userID = this.authenticationService.getUserId();
   this.userSettings = this.dbService.getUserSettings(userID)
   .then(responseData => {
  });
}
```

Desired results: the component to received the

```
this.retrievedSettings = setting;
```

Comment: Which one of your object you are expected to has the `retrievedSettings` propery? You use the `this` keyword inside your callback method.

Comment: Just use `const responseData = await this.http.get(…).toPromise()`, instead of dealing with observables in your `async function`.

Comment: Please, read the HttpClient guide: https://angular.io/guide/http. Don't subscribe in  the service. Don't have an instance field in the service. Don't make your method async. Simply return the observable from the service, and subscribe to the returned observable in the component. Your catchError which just rethrows the exact same error is completely useless, too.

Comment: @NimaBoobard Good question. I tried returning the setting property but it didn't work so I tried assigning it to retrievedSetting variable and that didn't work either.

Bergi I tried that, but then only 'undefined' data gets returned.

JBNizet Thanks for the useful link. I am really lost with observables and promises, and I have a bad habit of copying and pasting code I found from other peoples solutions on here without understanding the logic behind the code.